# Нужно ли закрывать запятой оборот с союзом КАК в устойчивом сочетании?

Tags: пунктуация, фразеология, обороты-с-как

1. **Попробуем не ставить запятую** в следующих предложениях (в практических текстах ее тоже не было):

*Не кто иной, **как Деникин** признал ненужность этого ведомства.*

*Не кто иной, **как Луначарский**  ввел эту важную поправку.*

2. В другой редакции:

*Не кто-то, **а сам  Деникин** признал ненужность этого ведомства.*

*Не кто-то, **а сам  Луначарский**  ввел эту важную поправку.*

3. Тогда зачем здесь запятая? Это же **обычное противопоставление** вида НЕ…А для однородных членов, а там запятой нет.

Можно ли  обосновать ее необходимость, указанную в правилах?

Comment: Ушло в чат всё-таки, лайк не спас, но, может, отсрочил.

Comment: Надо было несколько поставить :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Розенталь:
Запятая ставится перед *как* в оборотах *не кто иной, не что иное, как*. Например:
*Оказалось на поверку, что «человечек» не кто иной, как отставной приказный* (Салтыков-Щедрин).
*Спереди Рейнский водопад не что иное, как невысокий водяной уступ* (Жуковский).
Если указанными оборотами не заканчивается предложение, то часть их с союзом *как* выделяется запятыми с двух сторон, например:
*Не кто иной, как Петров, помог нам в этом случае.

Не что иное, как глубокое ущелье, открылось перед нашим взором.*

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129193/discussion-on-answer-by-oleedd---------).

Answer (score 1):

Пример Розенталя из классики с обособлением:
*На мгновенье ему показалось даже, что это не кто иной, как Валько, мог дать Володе Осьмухину такое задание* (Фадеев).

Comment: Спасибо, но у Розенталя этот пример есть в правилах.  Мне же неясна грамматическая конструкция, а Розенталь ничего не объясняет.  Мне кажется, я в каком-то старом учебнике видела объяснение: союз КАК равен союзу А, запятая не нужна. Но не помню где.

Comment: Эти союзы не равны, они просто похожи.